# Using strata to account for random effects in a permanova in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use permanova to test for treatment effects and interaction in a study design where blocking needs to be considered as a random effect, and one treatment is paired within the other.

There are plots with high or low density, and in each plot are subplots with treatment A in one subplot, treatment B in the other. The design is a latin square, with only one replicate of each treatment combination in each block effect (vertical blocking and horizontal blocking) so that blocking needs to be treated as a random effect.

The response variable is percent cover of plant species in the community.

The data is set up thus:

```
Treatment hblock    vblock  Inoc    sp1 sp2 …
1   1   1   1   0.2 0.25    
2   2   1   2   0.3 0.9 
1   3   1   2   0.2 0.2 
2   4   1   1   0.01    0.001
```

Where "Treatment" is the high and low density treatment, and "Inoc" is the treatment "A or B" in the subplots.

My question is, since I can't use random effects in permanova, so far as I can tell from reading about it, can I account for the blocking effects by nesting the interaction within the blocks - like this:

```
adonis(formula = temp[, -c(1:4)] ~ temp$Inoc * temp$Treatment , method = "bray", strata = temp$Vblock * temp$Hblock,      permuatations = 1000)
```

Or is this approach invalid?

Comment: Since this question is about how to account for blocking, not a question about how to properly code a statistical test you're certain is appropriate for your data, it may be better fit for cross validated than stack overflow

Comment: OK, thank you, I will try that!